# Why do I get two different kinds of notifications from chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, push-notification, notifications, web-push

Web push notifications. Why do I get two different kinds of chrome notifications on two different machines (Both windows 10, latest chrome version), generated from the same source - https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/?

This is making the behaviour inconsistent.

[image: Chrome notification type 1]

[image: Chrome notification type 2]

The second image is from my personal machine, first image is from VM (probably with some restrictions, which I'm not aware of.) How can we generate these two kinds of notifications? Are there any particular settings ..?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, Windows doesn't look the same... you have two different designs also for the Windows taskbar! Maybe you are using different themes or configurations...

In any case every device has its own way to display push notifications and you should not worry about that.

Comment: Agreed. One was my personal machine, one was a VM (probably with some restrictions, which I'm not aware of.)
How can we generate these two kinds of notifications? Is there any particular settings ..?

Comment: @NishantRai The website owner / sender cannot change the appearance of the notifications. You can only set the contents. The layout and style are defined by the browser / OS.